# Function of single variable $f(x)$, $f(x+y)=f(xy)$ and the exponential.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

For a function of a single variable $f(x)$ which has the property that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ we first set $x=y=0$ and then develop an ODE to show that $f(x)=\exp\{-\beta x\}$.

I do not understand how setting $x=y=0$ gives us $f(0)=1$ before we know that we have the exponential? Then I don't understand how we can set the following ODE up.
\begin{equation}
\frac{df(x)}{dx}=-\beta f(x)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{where} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \beta=-f'(x)
\end{equation}
Which doesn't contain any information on $y$. I do however understand that the solution to that ODE is the exponential I am after. Many thanks!

Comment: Well, since $f(0)=f(0)^2$, then $f(0)$ is either $0$ or $1$. If it is $0$, then $f(x)=f(x+0)=f(x)f(0)=0$ and $f$ is the zero function. If this is not the case, then it must be $1$.

Comment: Two hints, which someone will probably write as an answer before I've finished. 1. Set $x = y= 0$ in the equation $f$ satisfies. That tells you something about $f(0)$. 2. Use the definition of the derivative as the limit of $(f(x+h) - f(x))/h$ as $h$ approaches $0$.

Comment: Oh guys I must be having a bad day! Thank you both very much indeed!

Comment: Though apparently the equation doesn't contain any information about $y$, this is not a problem because $y$ is not what you are looking for, it is just an arbitrary real number. Knowing $f(x)$ for all $x$ also tells you $f(xy)$ given $x$ and $y$ (the numbers are just given names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\, x = y = 0\,$ we have $\, f(0+0) = f(0)\cdot f(0).\,$ 
Let us denote $\,f_0:=f(0),\,$ then
$$
f_0 = f_0^2 \implies 
\begin{cases}
f_0 = 1\\
f_0 = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Note that for any $x\in\Bbb R\,$ $\,f(x + 0) = f(x)\cdot f(0)$.
Thus we conclude that the second case $\,f_0 = 0\,$ is trivial. 
Indeed, if $\,f(0) = 0\,$ then 
$\,
f(x + 0) = f(x)\cdot f(0) = f(x)\cdot 0 = 0,\,
$
and thus $\,f(x) \equiv 0.\,$

Therefore we choose the first case $\,f_0 = f(0) = 1.\,$